# While loop only running once even though it's in a foreach

Tags: php, xml, csv

I have an array of ids and an array of file names. I am looping through each id that maps to ids in a CSV file.

The idea of the script is to loop through these ids and create an xml file for each of the file names based on the id. The problem being that the while loop that creates the structure and takes the content from the csv file only seems to run for the first id. (Though the foreach does still loop through each one?

my code:

```
<?php
echo "working .. wait";
ob_flush();
flush();
if (($handle = fopen("air_quality.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    # define the tags - last col value in csv file is derived so ignore
    $header = array('id', 'desc', 'date', 'time', 'nox', 'no', 'no2', 'lat', 'long');

    # throw away the first line - field names
    fgetcsv($handle, 200, ",");

    # count the number of items in the $header array so we can loop using it
    $cols = count($header);

    #set record count to 1
    $count = 1;
    # set row count to 2 - this is the row in the original csv file
    $row = 2;

    $ids = array(3,6,8,9,10,11);
    $xml_files = array('brislington.xml', 'fishponds.xml', 'parson_st.xml', 'rupert_st.xml', 'wells_rd.xml', 'newfoundland_way.xml');

    # start ##################################################
    foreach($ids as $key=>$value) {
        $out = '<records>';

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 200, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                    if ($data[0] == $value) {
                $rec = '<row count="' . $count . '" id="' . $row . '">';

                for ($c=0; $c < $cols; $c++) {
                    $rec .= '<' . trim($header[$c]) . ' val="' . trim($data[$c]) . '"/>';
                }
                $rec .= '</row>';
                $count++;
                $out .= $rec;
            }
            $row++;
        }

            echo $value;
        $out .= '</records>';

        # finish ##################################################

        # write out file
     file_put_contents($xml_files[$key], $out);
     fgetcsv($handle, 200, ",") === TRUE;
    }

    fclose($handle);



}
echo "....all done!";
?>
```

It does create all the XML files but only the first one has the content. The expected out put if 6 xml files with data taken from the csv file. These are the created files:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show where does `$handle` come from and so it doesn't seem to depend on outer loop.

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code, example data, expected output and what output you're currently getting.  Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Rarst updated with full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop reuses `$handle` so after first iteration the pointer is already at the end of file and won't go over it again. You probably need to `rewind( $handle )` after every iteration.